# Why did my question get closed as “opinion-based”?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67499217/best-way-to-get-the-same-data-in-parent-and-child-component-in-angularjs) is asking something about performance. The expected response has to be based on fact comparing two different ways to do something.

Only one way is better than the other way. So only one answer can be. If only one answer is possible how can it be opinion-based?

I've seen similar questions to mine like [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792652/what-is-the-best-way-to-conditionally-apply-a-class) which did not get closed. I could make a list but that not the point. I know sometimes question get through.
But starting from the fact that my question has ONE true answer how it could be an opinion?

Did I not asked properly the question or is it just hasard? Are some questions judge okay based on your reputation?

Plus my question will really help us, our team and I got not just ours.

Please help me find out why my question is closed it'll really help.

Comment: i mean, like, that's just your opinion of your question,

Comment: If you compare my question and the question I link what is the difference ?

Comment: The question you linked was asked 9 years ago. Then, the rules on Stack Overflow were different. Also, just because one question isn't closed doesn't mean yours should also stay open. So many questions get asked that some slip past curation activities.

Comment: My opinion is they're both primarily opinion based, but the one you linked to was treated as a "How do i do X" question rather than which way is the best. (which is how it should have been asked to begin with)

Comment: If you want to ask about better performance, you should specify how you measure performance. The "the best and most efficient way" is too unclear. Do you care about speed? Memory consumption? Easiest to maintain? Maybe least network traffic? If you do, then also the questions pops up why you aren't simply measuring the performance of both approaches yourself?

Comment: I think you should lean away from using "best way" and instead go solely with "most efficient," while also defining exactly what you mean by that. Do you mean fastest time? Best Big O notation? How are you measuring efficiency, and why is it important for your project? Remember that [premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil/80092#80092).

Comment: First thanks to take the time to answer me, it help understanding ! 
As I said "I know sometimes question get through" but in my opinion, if you think of it. If you asked which number is bigger 2 or 3 only on answer can be. Yes we could say depend on your opinion, but mathematically only one answer can be. 

Me question was what way more efficient, I guess some smatter guy than me made some performance test to know. Only one answer which is not an opinion can be true...

Comment: @crg: If you ask "which number is bigger, 2 or 3", then that question is fine. But if you ask "which number is better, 2 or 3", then better has to be defined.

Comment: you can i do a or B and this is not opionbased?

Comment: "My sort is 80% faster, which is what you wanted"..."Yeah, OK, but I don't have 32GB of RAM and a ThreadRipper"..."That's not my problem, pay my invoice".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question, IMO, is clearly opinion-based. It is asking for the "best way" to do something. There's no doubt about that being opinion-based. To one person, it might seem like doing "A" is the only solution, but to another, it may seem that "B" is the better choice. That is the definition of opinion-based.

> Only one way is better than the other way. So only one answer can be. If only one answer is possible how can it be opinion-based?

Well, opinion-based questions tend to attract more than one answer. So only one answer *cannot* be, because the answerer will claim that their way is better. That's why opinion-based questions aren't allowed in the first place.

Stack Overflow is a database of *factual* knowledge, not opinions.

> Did I not asked properly the question or is it just hasard? Are some questions judge okay based on your reputation?

Nobody judges questions based on the reputation of the user who asked them. We vote on content, not the people.

If you wish for the question to get reopened, I'd suggest rewording it into a "How to" question, or a "Which is the most efficient?" question. You'll still get answers, and if you get an even better answer, you can accept that one instead.

It's the same question, just less opinion-based, and still guaranteed to get a correct answer.

Comment: Thank you @10rep So should I make another question based on your advices ? Or to edit this one and wait it to be re-opened ?

Comment: @crg np :). Edit your current question into shape. if you want, the folks at [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) can help you to edit it into shape. But be sure to follow the FAQ of the room though.

Comment: @crg one recommendation though is "most efficient" is ambigious.  So if you are looking for most efficient, make sure you clarify what efficient means.  Does it mean shortest code?  Does it mean least memory?  Does it mean shortest execution time?

Comment: Okay thanks, it help me ! I was actually thinking to use  "most efficient". Not so easy to rewrite a question for a beginner.

Comment: "So should I make another question based on your advices ?" - You should never ask the same question after a question has already been closed.  Your existing question must be reopened.  Asking the same question will just result in duplicate flags of the original question.

Answer (score 15):

"Best" and "most efficient"-style questions are easy close bait.

You're going to want to restructure your question *entirely* so that you're asking a single objective question, like, "what would be the performance implications of doing X in Y way, if I have Z constraints?"