# Can a reopened question get closed again?

Tags: discussion, support

Yesterday I asked «[*Why did my question get closed as “opinion-based”?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407643/why-did-my-question-get-closed-as-opinion-based?noredirect=1#comment842962_407643)».

[The question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67499217/most-efficient-way-to-get-the-same-data-in-parent-and-child-component-in-angular) has been reopened after I edited it, thanks to the community's help.

And now it is voted back to be closed, but for me it does not make sense. If my question is reopened, doesn't it mean that a trusted user validated the question?

Can it be reclosed just after it has been reopened?

Comment: Yes, it can be closed and then reopened and then closed again and reopened etc. There's just a restriction on single users casting their votes (unless they are mods or SE employees).

Comment: MSE FAQ: [What are the limits on how I can cast, change, and retract votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5212)

Comment: You might have gotten some sympathy votes to reopen but the edits haven't changed the fact it's still an opinion based issue. It also seems you already know which approach is more efficient

Comment: You accepted the answer on Meta that explains why your question is opinion based and currently it still is. Why don't you ask: *This code in api.js gets called twice, once from parent and once from child. I would like to have it only called once, by whoever gets there first. How can I achieve that?* And if network blah blah is important, include your measurements, current timings and explain what you're aiming for (for example: I like to reduce the number of calls to 1 or load time should be < 500 ms or memory size< 1MB)

Comment: A question can be closed again after it was re-opened. Happens a lot: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1408143 some even go through that cycle more then once.

Comment: @charlietfl yes I have been answered which approach is more efficient. But the question was already in the process to be re-opened. Now it is just about curiosity on the close-open process.

Comment: @crg The real reason your post was closed, reopened and closed again was because of the [meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect). When you call such intense attention to a single post, individual users' strong opinions cause wild swings. Those users likely came across your main site question after visiting your meta site question.